# Android Studio does not start emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-electric-eel

I just installed Android Studio (Electric Eel) on a new device. Unfortunately, it does not start any emulator. I tried it with several different emulators. A Window pops up stating "Connecting to the Emulator" but nothing happens, even when I wait for 30 minutes. After 300 seconds I get a timeout error message but still it says "Connecting to the Emulator". I tried to start an app and I also tried to do a cold boot. Before that I deleted all emulators and added a new one. Still, the problem persists.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening? I have about 20 GB of free disc space so this should not be the problem.

**Update**: I tried to run the emulator from Windows command line and received the following output (the emulator still does not start):

```
C:\Users\wi9632\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools>emulator -avd Pixel_6_API_33
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 141.3.175.71
INFO    | IPv6 DNS server found: 2a00:1398::5
INFO    | IPv6 DNS server found: 2a00:1398::6
INFO    | IPv6 DNS server found: fe80::1
ANGLE: D3D11: rx::Renderer11::generateConfigs
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_posture_requested(int) ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_posture_selection_dialog() ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_resizable_requested(PresetEmulatorSizeType) ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_resizable_dialog() ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll
ANGLE: egl::`anonymous-namespace'::CreateDisplayFromAttribs: make D3D display
ANGLE: D3D11: rx::Renderer11::generateConfigs
ERROR   | Could not make GLES 2.x context current!
ERROR   | Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
ERROR   | Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

INFO    | Sending adb public key [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 @unknown]
INFO    | Warning: QCssParser::parseHexColor: Unknown color name '#FFFFFFs' ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | injectedQemuChannel!
INFO    | Informing listeners of injection.
INFO    | Rootcanal has  been activated.
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\localadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_10724.ini
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,0) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,1) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,2) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,3) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,4) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,5) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,6) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,7) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,8) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,9) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,10) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,11) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,12) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,13) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,14) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,15) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,16) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,17) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,18) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,19) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,20) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,21) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,22) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,23) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,24) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,25) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,26) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,27) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,28) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,29) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,30) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,31) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,32) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,33) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,34) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,35) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,36) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,37) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,38) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,39) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,40) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,41) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,42) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,43) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,44) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,45) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,46) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,47) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,48) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,49) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,50) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,51) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,52) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,53) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,54) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,55) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,56) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,57) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,58) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,59) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,60) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,61) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,62) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,63) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,64) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,65) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,66) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,67) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,68) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,69) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,70) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,71) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,72) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,73) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,74) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,75) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,76) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,77) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,78) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,79) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,80) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,81) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,82) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,83) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,84) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,85) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,86) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,87) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,88) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,89) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,90) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,91) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,92) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,93) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,94) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,95) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,96) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,97) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,98) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,99) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,100) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,101) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,102) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,103) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,104) out of range ((null):0, (null))

Failed to sync vcpu reg
INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,105) out of range ((null):0, (null))
Failed to sync vcpu reg

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,106) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,107) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,108) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,109) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,110) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,111) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,112) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,113) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,114) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,115) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,116) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,117) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,118) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,119) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,120) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,121) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,122) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,123) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,124) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,125) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,126) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,127) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,128) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,129) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,130) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,131) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,132) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,133) out of range ((null):0, (null))

ERROR   | OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.

2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).

3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" to "Swiftshader".

Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup.
INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,134) out of range ((null):0, (null))


INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,135) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,136) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,137) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,138) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,139) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,140) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,141) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,142) out of range ((null):0, (null))
ERROR   | crashhandler_die: fatal: OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize. Please consider the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Make sure your GPU drivers are up to date.

2. Erase and re-download the emulator ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator).

3. Try software rendering: Go to Extended Controls > Settings > Advanced tab and change "OpenGL ES renderer (requires restart)" to "Swiftshader".

Or, run emulator from command line with "-gpu swiftshader_indirect". 4. Please file an issue to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 and provide your complete CPU/GPU info plus OS and display setup.


INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,143) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,144) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,145) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,146) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,147) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,148) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,149) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,150) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,151) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,152) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,153) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,154) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,155) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,156) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,157) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,158) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,159) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,160) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,161) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,162) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,163) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,164) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,165) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,166) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,167) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,168) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,169) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,170) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,171) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,172) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,173) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,174) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,175) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,176) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,177) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,178) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,179) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,180) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,181) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,182) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,183) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,184) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,185) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,186) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,187) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,188) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,189) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,190) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,191) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,192) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,193) out of range ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Warning: QImage::pixel: coordinate (1209,194) out of range ((null):0, (null))
```

**Update 2**:
When I now want to start the Emulator in Android Studio, I get the information, that I should install HAXM. When I try to install it, I get the error message:

```
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Intel HAXM installation failed!
For more details, please check the installation log: C:\Users\LOCALA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_install-20230331_1113.log
Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows
```

I then followed the instructions and manually installed it which was successfull. However, I still get the error message when starting the emulator via Android Studio about HAXM. I also made sure that the Virtualization is enabled in Bios and that Hyper-V is deactivated in Windows.

Can you infer something out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had an older version of Intel Haxm installed that blocked the installation of the newer version which was needed to run the emulator. So I deleted the old version and installed the new Version of Intel Haxm via Android Studio. Now it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can get more error info by starting the emulator from the command line: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Also, as an option, you may try to downgrade the emulator to the previous version as described here: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive

Comment: Thanks sdex for your answer. I tried to start the emulator via the Windows console but this did not help. I added the output into my question. Any idea, what the problem might be?